# How to do matmul operation in specific dimension in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a 3D tensor **(sequence_length, batch_size, word_dim)**, I need to do matmul operation with **"word_dim" dimension** so that I can change tensor into **(sequence_length, batch_size, hidden_dim)**. It seems that matmul operation can only be used in 2D tensor. And I can not change the 3D tensor into 2D because of the "batch_size". How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I would first reshape your Tensor to be **(sequence_length * batch_size, word_dim)**, do the matmul to get **(sequence_length * batch_size, hidden_dim)**, then reshape again to get **(sequence_length, batch_size, hidden_dim)**. There is no copying involved with reshape(), and this is equivalent to multiplying each of the batch_size matrices individually if you only have one matrix to multiply them with.